# Managing Linked List Memory

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

Recently I have been using C a lot (I normally use higher level languages) and have been running into a problem when managing lists.

Specifically, adding nodes to a linked list.  I often end up writing something similar to the sample code below.  As far as I can see, it should all work fine however no new nodes are appended to the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode* next;
    int data;
} ListNode;

ListNode* createListNode(int data){
    ListNode* node = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void addListNode(ListNode* list, ListNode* newListNode){
    ListNode* current;

    if(list == NULL){
        list = newListNode;
    }else{
        current = list;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newListNode;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int ii;
    ListNode* list = NULL;
    ListNode* newListNode = NULL;
    int fakeData[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    for(ii=0; ii<=2; ii++){
        newListNode = createListNode(fakeData[ii]);
        addListNode(list, newListNode);
    }

    printf("%d", list->data);
    printf("%d", list->next->data);
    printf("%d", list->next->next->data);

    return 0;
}
```

When stepping through the code with a debugger, `addListNode` works as expected in a local context however, when returning to main the changes are lost and `list` is still equal to `NULL`.  But `list` is defined in main so it should be in scope and available until that function ends. Right?

If I make a small change to main like this.

```
for(ii=0; ii<=2; ii++){
    if(ii==0){
        list = createListNode(fakeData[ii]);
    }else{
        newListNode = createListNode(fakeData[ii]);
        addListNode(list, newListNode);
    }
}
```

It works fine. Why would that be?

I could do it like this, but I don't want to have linked list specific code floating everywhere.

Clearly, I'm missing something quite fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void addListNode(ListNode* list, ListNode* newListNode)
```

This should be ListNode **list, otherwise the function really won't change it's value.
The list = newListNode; command won't have any effect outside the function.

Use ListNode **list, and when you want to change the value just say *list = newListNode;

Comment: This seemed to resolve it.  Why would I use a double pointer?  The list is defined as a normal pointer, wouldn't that be enough.

Comment: `main()` passed a *copy* of `ListNode *list` to `addListNode()`, which would have been unable to modify the original copy. Passing a double-pointer is analogous to passing `ListNode *list` by reference.

Another solution would be to separate the roles of creating a brand-new list and adding more members to a list. Have `main()` call `createListNode()` if the list ptr is NULL, otherwise use `addListNode()` to add more items.

Comment: Because you want to change the pointer itself, not just the value it's pointed to. To do that you need the address of the pointer, therefore it needs to be a ListNode** rather than ListNode*